# I am not able to import an image into python using the import image way

Tags: python, image

Before you ask, I did try putting an image in it, and it didn't work like look at this.

```
import Image
Image = Image.open('clerky.jpeg')
Image.show()
```

and this code above comes up with this error below.

```
import Image
ImportError: No module named 'Image'
```

Comment: since that kind of importing works in python2 I assume you are using Pillow for python 3 or you installed PIL/Pillow for a different version that you tried importing from.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org), the [correct usage](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.x/handbook/tutorial.html) is

```
from PIL import Image
```

To install Pillow on Windows, start the `Command Prompt` application (or hit <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd`, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Type

```
pip install Pillow
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and everything should install automatically.

Comment: how do i know which bit of python im uing

Comment: @artechhelp don't worry about it. See my further edit above - once you open the Command Prompt, just type in `pip install Pillow` and it *should* do everything automatically.

Comment: @artechhelp OK, how do you run Python? From IDLE?

Comment: yeah i do run it from idle

Comment: @artechhelp OK, in IDLE type `import sys`, hit Enter, then type `print(sys.executable)` and run that as well. What is the output?

Comment: C:\Users\garg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\pythonw.exe

Comment: @artechhelp alrighty then, let's try this way. Still in IDLE, run `import pip`, then `pip.main(["install","Pillow"])`. Does that work?

Comment: You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\garg\Desktop\momwsbrothersappgame.py", line 4, in <module>
    Image=Image.open('clerky.jpeg')
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: @artechhelp you're overwriting `Image` by naming your variable the same thing. Try `img = Image.open("clerky.jpeg"); img.show()`.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: @artechhelp what happened when you ran the command I suggested above? Did you get a message that Pillow 3.2.0 was installed successfully? If so, did you then completely exit Python/IDLE and restart it?

Comment: yep heres the full form

Comment: You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\garg\Desktop\momwsbrothersappgame.py", line 4, in <module>
    Imge=Image.open('clerky.jpeg')
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
>>>

Comment: hello? any help plz?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `from PIL import Image`

Comment: it says no module called PIL

Comment: @artechhelp do you have PIL/Pillow installed?

Comment: Do you have `PIL` installed. i.e. - Have you done `pip install pillow` Where this would be in the shell

Comment: dude, we gotta stop copying each other ;)

Comment: i tried pip install pillow but it said incorrect syntax

Comment: @artechhelp you need to run that command from the *command line*, not from within a Python session...

Comment: @artechhelp you would need to do that in command prompt / terminal, you can do it from within python with `import pip ; pip.main(["install","Pillow"])`

Comment: sorry im a noobish at python can u tell me how to do that

Answer (score -3):

from PIL import Image

PIL (Python Image Library) has to be installed on your system, AKA "pil" and "Pillow" from time to time.  effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm

Comment: Your attempted link (remember, all URLs need to have a protocol like `http://`) is laughably out of date. PIL hasn't been updated since gods know how long. Pillow is a fork of PIL, and is under active development (the most recent version is 3.2.0).